# Adding OpenVPN keys to Kali Linux without root

Tags: permissions, kali-linux, root, openvpn, wget

I've been trying to run OpenVPN on Kali Linux using the [official openvpn guide](https://openvpn.net/vpn-software-packages/#modal-items) and ran the first command:

`sudo apt update && apt -y install ca-certificates wget net-tools gnupg`

Alls been updated and it seems the installation has gone well.

[image: installed ca-certificates and net-tools]

I run into an issue when I try to run the following:

```
sudo wget -qO - https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as-repo-public.gpg | apt-key add -echo "deb http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian buster main">/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list
```

[image: Permission Denied Error: OpenVPN Key Installation]

I ran `touch openvpn-as-repo.list` to ensure the file has been created to echo to, but it seems this is not the fix.

It appears this requires explicit root privileges. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a kali repository I'm supposed to use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question you need to run:

```
wget -qO - https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as-repo-public.gpg |sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian buster main" |sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list
```

The `openvpn` package is available on kali repo, you don't need to add a third party repository, just run:

```
sudo apt install openvpn
```